Can I generate a list of sentences from a list of words?
I want to take a group of words, ideally at least 100, and then get sentences that actually make sense.
Any grammar check API I've seen can correct sentences if they are in a form that at least resembles a correct sentences but when taking grouping random words, I get a lot of sentences that actually aren't correct. On one attempt with Natural Language Toolkit (NLTK) I was given the partial list:
door to me go
me go our game
go our game eight
game eight plays go
eight plays go me
my dog is blue you
dog is blue you her
is blue you her run.
all non-sensical.

Simply using combinatorics on the list is impossible because there are far too many possibilities, but I am unsure where else I can break things down. My latest attempt was to use a mix of itertools permutation and multiprocessing to check the random sentences while they are still being generated. Right now the check is with a large language database for already validated sentences, but other validation methods had the same results. 0 valid sentences after 1 hour. I don't need all possible sentences so it can stop after reaching a large number or or it just needs to possible to end early. I am still fairly new to coding so please be kind Here's the current implementations code:
import hashlib
import itertools
import multiprocessing
import time
import random
from nltk import pos_tag
from nltk.corpus import wordnet as wn
import nltk

# NLTK setup
nltk.download('averaged_perceptron_tagger')
nltk.download('wordnet')

# Force data load
pos_tag(['test'])
wn.synsets('dog')

def hash_sentence(sentence):
    """Hashes a sentence using SHA-256."""
    return hashlib.sha256(sentence.lower().encode()).hexdigest()

def generate_permutations(shared_list, words, max_length=7):
    """Generates filtered permutations of words and adds them to a shared list."""
    for r in range(2, max_length + 1):
        for perm in itertools.permutations(words, r):
            with shared_list.get_lock():  # Synchronize access
                shared_list.append(' '.join(perm))
    with shared_list.get_lock():
        shared_list.append(None)  # Signal that generation is complete

def validate_sentences(shared_list, hashed_sentences, output_file):
    """Validates sentences from a shared list against hashed sentences and writes valid ones to a file."""
    with open(output_file, 'a', encoding='utf-8') as file:
        while True:
            time.sleep(0.1)  # Small delay to allow generator to populate list
            with shared_list.get_lock():
                if not shared_list:
                    continue
                sentence = shared_list.pop(0)
            if sentence is None:
                break
            if hash_sentence(sentence) in hashed_sentences:
                print(f"Valid sentence: {sentence}")
                file.write(sentence + '\n')

def shuffle_list(shared_list):
    """Shuffles the sentences in the shared list every 3 minutes."""
    while True:
        time.sleep(180)  # Sleep for 3 minutes
        with shared_list.get_lock():
            # Shuffle all items except the termination signal (None) if it exists
            sentences = [s for s in shared_list if s is not None]
            random.shuffle(sentences)
            shared_list[:] = sentences
            if None in shared_list:
                shared_list.append(None)

def load_hashed_sentences(filepath):
    """Loads and hashes sentences from the Tatoeba dataset."""
    hashed_sentences = set()
    with open(filepath, 'r', encoding='utf-8') as file:
        next(file)  # Skip the header if present
        for line in file:
            parts = line.strip().split('\t')
            if parts[1] == 'eng':
                sentence_hash = hash_sentence(parts[2])
                hashed_sentences.add(sentence_hash)
    return hashed_sentences

def main():
    manager = multiprocessing.Manager()
    shared_list = manager.list()  # Shared list managed by the manager
    tsv_path = r"C:\Users\BaseC\Code\French\Sentence_Gen\eng_sentences.tsv"
    hashed_sentences = load_hashed_sentences(tsv_path)
    words = "my dog is blue you her run she orange cow door to me go our game eight plays go me A broad river runs through the city".split(' ')
    output_file = 'valid_sentences.txt'
    
    generator_process = multiprocessing.Process(target=generate_permutations, args=(shared_list, words, 7))
    validator_process = multiprocessing.Process(target=validate_sentences, args=(shared_list, hashed_sentences, output_file))
    shuffler_process = multiprocessing.Process(target=shuffle_list, args=(shared_list,))

    generator_process.start()
    validator_process.start()
    shuffler_process.start()

    generator_process.join()
    validator_process.join()
    shuffler_process.join()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()


You need to create a model of a valid sentence i.e. Noun, Verb, Noun as an example.  Then classify your list of words into the appropriate categories, and finally use those categories to formulate sentences. You may still end up with sentences which are nonsensical. Something like 'Cow run train'


Right now the check is with a large language database for already validated sentences

If that's your criterion for validity, then you could just iterate through the sentences in the database and select the ones that consist only of words in your word-list.
Alternatively, you could define a grammar whose terminals are the words in your word-list, and then use that to generate sentences that are valid according to that grammar. If it's a context-free grammar, this is fairly easy to do yourself, or you could use something like nltk.parse.generate.generate.
